# What is the difference between "ALTER DATABASE mydb SET search_path" and "SET search_path"?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.6. I just found *both* of these commands in a flyway migration, right next to each other. I feel like they are probably redundant but how do these statements differ? Is there a reason to use both? Apologies if this is a duplicate; I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ALTER DATABASE` will change the `search_path` for every **new** connection to that database. The change however does **not** affect current connections - including the one that ran the `ALTER DATABASE`. The `set search_path` then changes the path also for the current connection so that it has the same value as the default path.

Comment: So it's not redundant in my case. The search_path could be required later in the migration if the author of the migration scripts isn't unambiguous about table spaces. Do I have this correct?

Comment: @medley56: correct

Comment: @medley56: [Table spaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) are a completely different concept, unrelated to schemas. `ALTER DATABASE` only applies to new connections where there is no other (more specific) setting overruling it.

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways to set configuration parameters than just the two you found. None of them are redundant. There are various ways around default settings. And the `search_path` is almost always essential for general operation.

```
ALTER DATABASE test SET search_path = test, public;
```

... sets a default for connections to the database that overrules the default in `postgresql.conf`. But there are more specific options to overrule both. Settings for a particular role overrule settings for the database and settings for a particular role *in* a particular database overrule all of them. All of these are defaults for *new* connections. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html#AEN74674)

> Whenever the role subsequently starts a new session, the specified
>   value becomes the session default, overriding whatever setting is
>   present in `postgresql.conf` or has been received from the `postgres`
>   command line. This only happens at login time; executing [`SET ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-role.html) or
>   [`SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-session-authorization.html) does not cause new configuration values to
>   be set. Settings set for all databases are overridden by
>   database-specific settings attached to a role. Settings for specific
>   databases or specific roles override settings for all roles.

`SET search_path` executed in the current session always has the final say. *If* you execute that as first command of every session, defaults never do anything. But typically its wise to have reasonable defaults.

Here is a list of ways to set the `search_path` (or similar configuration parameters) and more explanation:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)